# Centre 2 line text in box

Tags: css, text, centering

I have 2 boxes with some text going across positioned in the centre of each box. The problem is when there is 2 lines of text the text doesn't get centred anymore.

[**Here's an example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waBozx)

The positioning of the text is made by the following CSS as the boxes have a hover effect:

```
margin: 50% 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
```

Any ideas on how to have the text always centred even when there is 2 or more lines of text?

Thank you!

Comment: This is the provided demo (added some images): http://jsbin.com/hupesa/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: (sorry created that demo cause waiting for images almost killed my patience :) ) I mean, your text is not even centered horizontally...

Comment: Do you know how can I fix that in order to have the text always centred even with 2 line text?

Comment: Yes, let me crate an example

Comment: Is the container (.block) DIV width and height dictated by the containing image? If yes, why?

Comment: mm no I don't think it is.

Comment: I cannot see you've set any width and height for that *block container*, that's why I'm asking...

Comment: Sorry yeah the width is dictated by the containing image. The main box div doesn't have any width it only has float left to make the boxes side by said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly AFAIK there's no way an element using CSS `scale()` can move other sibling elements, therefore in this demo I've just focused on centering both vertically and horizontally an element and it's text-content:

```css
.block{
  background: none 50% / cover; 
  display:    table;
  height:     480px;
  width:      360px;
}
.caption{
  position:       relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background:     rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align:     center;
  font-size:      1.25em;
  display:        table-cell;
  color:          #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/300x190)">
  <div class="caption">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor<br>sit amet<br></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I've used a hardcoded value of `40px` to move-up the title.
The same value is added to the margin-top of the absolute *description* text element beneath it (caveat: hopefully you can control the length of the description text so it won't overflow the overall element parent height...):

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}



.block{
  background: none 50% / cover; 
  display:    table;
  height:     480px;
  width:      360px;
  float:      left;
}
.caption{
  position:       relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background:     rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align:     center;
  font-size:      1.25em;
  display:        table-cell;
  color:          #fff;
}
.caption h2{
  transition:     0.5s;
  transform:      translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 15px;
}
.caption p{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-top:  -40px; /* (same value*) */
  transition:     0.5s;
  transform:  scale(0);
}
.caption p:before{ /* thin white line */
  background: #fff;
  position:   absolute;
  content:    "";
  margin:     0 auto;
  height:     1px;
  width:      15%;
  right: 0; left: 0;top: 0;  
}
.block:hover h2{
  transform: translate3d(0, -40px, 0); /* (same value*) */
}
.block:hover p{
  transform:  scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="block" style="background-image:url(http://topwalls.net/wallpapers/2012/04/flame-nebula-Space--480x360.jpg)">
  <div class="caption">
    <h2>Centered no matter how much text </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor<br>sit amet<br>qwer<br>ASDF</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/300x190)">
  <div class="caption">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor<br>sit amet<br></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

note that I've removed the `<img>` element, so you won't be dependent on that image size cause it could mess up your content. Instead it's a background-image that will fully-cover the cotnainer block element. If you want to make those parents responsive simply use `%` for *size (W/H)* instead of `px`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!! Thank you so much for your help!!